# Preferred Linux driver architecture for a multi-function PMU device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, gpio

I have a bespoke/complex Power Management Unit which exposes its functionality as an I2C slave with 16-bit registers and an interrupt (out) signal.

This PMU also has GPIO functionality.

(The interrupt tells the Linux kernel (I2C master) to read registers because a GPIO input has changed state).

Currently, I've structured the (working) driver(s) as:

```
./include/linux/mfd/mypmu.h
./drivers/gpio/gpio-mypmu.c
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-core.c
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-regmap.c
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-i2c.c
```

I have three MODULE_DESCRIPTION() macro invocations:

```
./drivers/gpio/gpio-mypmu.c:MODULE_DESCRIPTION("GPIO interface for MYPMU");
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-core.c:MODULE_DESCRIPTION("MYMU device");
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-i2c.c:MODULE_DESCRIPTION("MYPMU_I2C");
```

The reason that it's split into three separate modules is that I use different ways of registering each module, according to the kernel subsystem of which they are a part.

```
./drivers/gpio/gpio-mypmu.c:platform_driver_register(&mypmu_gpio_driver);
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-core.c:platform_set_drvdata(*pdev, mypmu);
./drivers/mfd/mypmu-i2c.c:i2c_add_driver(&mypmu_i2c_driver);
```

(This is largely cargo-cult programming, caused by aping other (single-function) drivers' code.)

Is using three modules in one device driver normal?  Or is there a way to register one driver in multiple Linux subsystems, such as GPIO and I2C?

Can a driver appear in `/sys/class/gpio` without a module living in the `drivers/gpio` tree?

Is there a better way of structuring an MFD driver?

Comment: You can register multiple drivers in the same module.

Comment: For example, in "drivers/tty/serial/", "icom.c", "pch_uart.c", and "rp2.c" all register as both UART and PCI drivers. "serial_txx9.c" registers as UART, platform and (optionally) PCI drivers.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, looking at `icom_init()` I can see that the driver has two distinct structs, `icom_uart_driver` and `icom_pci_driver`.  That was what I'd missed from looking at single-function drivers.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.